# Why is there no data when Dates are null?

Tags: jquery, datatables

When using the column filter plugin for Jquery Datatables. I am trying to filter by date-range. When any of the dates are null, the table does not display any data. The data is passed to the page fine, but no data is being displayed:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="activeProjects">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Project Number</th>
                <th>Market</th>
                <th>Project Type</th>
                <th>Completion Date</th>
                <th>Square Footage</th>
                <th>Architect</th>
                <th>Manager</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="project in model.projects">
                <td></td>
                <td><a href></a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="clear">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#activeProjects').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "../api/Project/GetAll/",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                {
                    "aTargets": [1],
                    "mRender": function(data) {
                        return '<a href="ExistingProject?jobNumber=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                    }
                }
            ],
            "sPlaceHolder": "head:before",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "ProjectName" },
                { "data": "ProjectNumber" },
                { "data": "MarketName" },
                { "data": "ProjectTypeName" },
                { "data": "DateCompleted" },
                { "data": "SquareFoot" },
                { "data": "ProjectManager" },
                { "data": "ProjectArchitect" }
            ],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            }).columnFilter({
                aoColumns: [
                { type: "text", },
                { type: "text" }, 
                { type: "text" }, 
                { type: "text" }, 
                { type: "date-range" }, 
                { type: "text" }, 
                { type: "text" }, 
                { type: "text" } 
                ]
            });
    });

    $('#clear').click(function() {
        location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

If I change the filter type from date-range to text like the others then all the data displays. Any idea why this is and how I can tell it nulls are okay?

Comment: Possibly silly question, but are you including the [date-range filter](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/row-based/range_dates)?

Comment: @annoyingmouse Yes, The filter shows up on the screen but since the dates are null / " " the data doesn't show up.

Comment: Looks as though the filter checks for empty strings: `if ( iFini === "" && iFfin === "" )`, from what you said the fields aren't empty but have one space? Perhaps trim the value before parsing it? Something like `var iFini = document.getElementById('fini').value.trim();` and `var iFfin = document.getElementById('ffin').value;`. Just tried this in the console and it seems that if `var b = " ";` then `console.log(b.substring(6,10) + b.substring(3,5)+ b.substring(0,2));` gives `" "` whereas if `var b = "";` then `console.log(b.substring(6,10) + b.substring(3,5)+ b.substring(0,2));` gives `""`.

Comment: @annoyingmouse Sorry I didn't mean to put a space in the quotes. The problem is the field is not a valid date. So If I go in the Database and add valid dates then the table is populated with all of the data that has valid dates. IF they are null then the table does not populate them because there is no way to sort by that. I need to tell columnFilter to show the dates that are null as well as populated.

Comment: @annoyingmouse I just noticed the link you posted is not the filter I am using. I am using [Datatables columnFilter Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/)

Comment: I'm afraid that I've not used that particular plugin, though I might in the future as it seems to offer something I've needed and hacked myself before. Do you want, perhaps, to put up an example on JSFiddle so we can look at the code and experiment?